# ASP.NET Core Identity : a second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I get an error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

when I am trying to add a user role using the `AddToRoleAsync` function. I have seen a lot of posts saying missing await but everything is correct. Below is the code that I am using.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterCustomer(UserForRegisterCustomerDto userForRegisterCustomerDto)
{
        userForRegisterCustomerDto.UserName = userForRegisterCustomerDto.Email;

        var userToCreate = _mapper.Map<Users>(userForRegisterCustomerDto);

        var userVehicleToCreate = _mapper.Map<CustomerVehicles>(userForRegisterCustomerDto.CustomerVehicles);



        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userForRegisterCustomerDto.Password);

        var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<UserForDetailedDto>(userToCreate);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userForRegisterCustomerDto.Email);
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(currentUser, "Customer");
            userVehicleToCreate.UserId = currentUser.Id;

            _repo.Add(userVehicleToCreate);

            if (await _repo.SaveAll())
            {
                string confirmationToken = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(currentUser);
                //ConfirmEmail(currentUser.Id, confirmationToken);
                return Ok(userToReturn);
            }
        }

        return BadRequest(result.Errors);
    }
```

My Startup.cs is

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

adding ServiceLifetime.Transient doesn't resolve this issue.  Please suggest.

Error is:

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Demo.API.Models.DataContext'.
      System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by
different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.IsInRoleAsync(TUser user, String normalizedRoleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, String role)
   at Demo.API.Controllers.AuthController.RegisterCustomer(UserForRegisterCustomerDto userForRegisterCustomerDto) in F:\test\Demo\Demo.API\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 66
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker,
Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task
lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: are you using a `unitOfWork`?

Answer (score 0):

then add this instead

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration
.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")).UseQueryTrackingBehaviour(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Users' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'}
is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using
'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from the way you create the models.

solution: handle NULL fields and check the models.

and also if you have operations with fields such as Login, Username, SignInManager, or something else that relate to classes and models in your _Layout view check them... error rise from them.